How to plot charts on Flutter with DateTime on Axis x
I have to implement a chart on my app that has DateTime values on the x axis. I am currently using fl_chart, but has some open issue regarding charts with DateTime values on the x axis which prevent me from continuing to use this library (#462, #438).
Which library can I use to plot this kid of graph and that is al least a bit customizable on colors and style?

This package syncfusion provides a lot of customization options.
For your problem, you can choose the type of the axis:

Category
Numeric
Date-time
Logarithmic

You can customize the xAxis as a DateTime axis.
SfCartesianChart(
    primaryXAxis: DateTimeAxis(
        minimum: DateTime(2010),
        maximum: DateTime(2020)
    )
)
          


Please note - this package has certain licensing requirements based on your use of it. https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts/license

@thenry oh yes, they already mentioned that in their docs, it's commercial.

thank you, i'll try to get a free individual license, because seems to be the only options
